# Infinitive and Gerund Construction

Tags: verbs, infinitives, gerunds, licensing

English isn't my mother tongue. I'm familiar with the notions of infinitive and gerund but I sometimes just don't know which of the two should be used in combination with which verb.

Thomson and Martinet [1986] provide some verbs that may take either infinitive or gerund without changing the meaning (advise, allow, ...).

I am looking for a list of verbs and the allowed construction (gerund/infinitive/both). Ideally this should be a text-based list so I can search it on my computer without having to use the internet.

[Thomson and Martinet, 1986] A. J. Thomson and A. V. Martinet, *A Practical English Grammar,* Oxford University Press, *isbn: 0-19-431342-5,* 1986.

Comment: **To those contemplating closevoting**: there is considerable sentiment for [allowing](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316/) questions of this sort; so I suggest withholding your closevote until the matter is resolved.

Comment: @StoneyB Might want to deal with the same issue here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/online-resources-for-learning-english

Comment: @StoneyB: I agree, I think this question is fine. In fact, we have a similar question EL&U somewhere, if only I could find it...

Comment: The question [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) on *English Language and Usage* is what you need. The first answer contains lists.

Comment: @Cerberus Would you consider posting your comment as an answer, as it solved the OP's problem (and doing so would remove this question from the Unanswered Questions list?).

Comment: @WendiKidd: Done! You know I can't not do whatever you request...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) on *English Language and Usage* is what you need. The first answer contains lists, which I'll reproduce here

> There is a copy of The Brief Penguin Handbook [here](http://wps.pearsoned.ca/ca_ab_faigley_penghdbk_1/64/16472/4216869.cw/-/t/index.html);
>   the **Verbs Followed by Gerunds or Infinitives** section is [here](http://wps.pearsoned.ca/ca_ab_faigley_penghdbk_1/64/16478/4218569.cw/index.html).
>
> The only way to know is to memorize which verbs are followed by gerunds and which are followed by infinitives. The relevant categories are:
>
> ### Verbs Followed by Infinitives
>
> Most verbs are followed by infinitives.
>   If the verb is not found in the list below, it is probably followed by an infinitive.
>
> ### Verbs Followed by Gerunds
>
> The verbs in the following table all need to be followed by gerunds.
>
> The students don’t enjoy going over the same rules again and again.

- admit (to)
- appreciate
- avoid
- be accustomed to
- be used to
- can’t help
- consider
- delay
- deny
- discuss
- dislike
- enjoy
- feel like
- finish
- get used to
- imagine
- keep (on)
- look forward to
- (not) mind
- miss
- postpone
- practice
- put off
- recommend
- regret
- report
- resent
- resist
- risk
- stop
- suggest
- tolerate
- understand

### Verbs Followed by an Object Before the Infinitive Verb

> I advise **you** to go to school early today.

- advise
- allow
- *ask
- authorize
- cause
- challenge
- convince
- encourage
- *expect
- force
- get
- help
- hire
- inform
- instruct
- invite
- *need
- order
- permit
- persuade
- *prepare
- *promise
- remind
- require
- teach
- tell
- train
- urge
- *want
- *warn
- *would like

*Some words can be used without an object as well as with an object.

> I want him to go. I want to go.

### Verbs Followed by Either Gerund or Infinitive

Sometimes the meaning changes according to the verb used.

> He doesn’t remember giving the homework to Mr. Young.
>      He didn’t remember to give the homework to Mr. Young.

- attempt
- begin
- can (not) bear
- can (not) stand
- continue
- hate
- intend
- (dis)like
- love
- neglect
- prefer
- remember
- start
- try

### Verbs Followed Only by the Simple Form (no “-ing” or “to”)

Four verbs are called causative verbs.
They are followed by an object; the verb after the object is always in the simple form:

- **let**: They let him go on the trip (instead of “let him to go”).

> I let him take my book home for one night.

- **make**: We made her do her chores first.

> I made my sister cry.

- **help**: She helped her finish her homework.

> I helped him find the bookstore.

- **have**: The teacher had him stay after school.

> I had my teacher explain the answers.

### Verbs Followed by Either the Simple Form or the Gerund (no “to”)

Some verbs are called verbs of perception and are followed by either the simple form or the “-ing” form.

- **see**: I see him go.

> I see him going.

- **notice**: I notice him run to school every day.

> I notice him running to school every day.

- **watch**: I watch him struggle with his homework.

> I watch him struggling with his homework.

- **hear**: I hear him sing.

> I hear him singing.

Others including: look at, observe, listen to, feel, smell.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for pulling the referenced post in here!

Comment: What would "inform you to" mean?

Comment: @FrancisDavey: Yeah, that doesn't sound right to me. I can find a couple of examples, but they all seem dubious: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inform+you+to%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE8dLlub3ZAhWE3KQKHWyPBccQpwUIHw&biw=1080&bih=1701&dpr=1

Comment: Yes, none of the actual examples look right to me. I'd mark them as ungrammatical if I were proof reading.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: I've asked a question in a comment on the original answer. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive#comment1038729_330