# Online Resources for Learning English

Tags: pedagogy

I teach a module that includes technical writing. More than 50% of the students are non-native English speakers. I'd like to provide some pointers to online resources that may be useful to students like this.

I welcome your suggestions and the reasons why you recommend them.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/, obviously   :-)

Comment: @mcalex I told the students about the forum but they should also be encouraged to teach themselves.

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm afraid this question is a bit too broad for the site. There are tons of good sources online, and we would get a very long or very disparate list. Maar hartelijk welkom verder!

Comment: @Cerberus no problem. Could you recommend a different place where I could ask this question?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I don't know, but I would probably just Google it if I were you, and maybe specify a little bit what you need exactly.